# Windows Authentication on Azure VM using Azure AD account from remote client

Tags: sql-server, azure

Issue

When connecting with Windows Authentication "Cannot connect to 172.16.1.5. The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context." Nothing appears in the SQL Server log.

Environment/Configuration

O365 Azure VM

- SQL Server Standard 2016 SP1, Default Instance, installed on Windows Server 2016
- Windows & SQL Server Authentication enabled
- Allow Remote Connections To This Server Enabled
- Configuration Manager>Protocols for MSSQLSERVER>TCP/IP -> all enabled (IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, IPALL) port 1433

Azure Joined Workstation

- Connected using Peer to Site VPN to Azure virtual network
- SSMS 17, can successfully connect using IP or host name using SQL Server Authentication.

Diagnostics

Kerberos Configuration Manager reports that "TCP must be enabled to use Kerberos Authentication on SQL Service 2016 Standard Edition Engine"
Windows Firewall is off (temporary while troubleshooting connectivity).
It's probably something ridiculous, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you try solutions in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2443457/you-may-experience-connectivity-issues-to-sql-server-if-spns-are-misco), please let me know the result on your side

Comment: @Nancy Xiong - MSFT thank you for the suggestion and the link. I used a tool called Kerberos Configuration Manager created by Microsoft which checks the SPNs and they were fine. Am open to other ideas.